# Laravel Forge multiple top level domains (TLD) redirect to one site with SSL

Tags: nginx, laravel-forge

Has someone managed to set up multiple top level domains for one site on Laravel Forge, with SSL for each domain. Additionally all domains should redirect to one main domain.

e.g.

main domain: `themaindomain.com`

other domains should be redirected to `https://themaindomain.com`

`http://example.com` -> `https://themaindomain.com`

`http://www.example.com` -> `https://themaindomain.com`

`https://example.com` -> `https://themaindomain.com`

`https://www.example.com` -> `https://themaindomain.com`

I just set it up like this blog post: https://blog.laravel.com/forge-alias-domains but now when i go to `http://www.example.com` it just redirects to `https://example.com`, but it should redirect to `https://themaindomain.com/` to avoid duplicate content.

I have added a Let's Encrypt through Laravel Forge where I added all domains in one request:

`themaindomain.com,www.themaindomain.com,example.com,www.example.com`

That worked as expected, only thing missing is the correct redirect

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the only way to do this without manually altering the nginx config is by creating a separate site for example.org (which also covers [www.example.org](http://www.example.org)) and then add a redirect at the app level with the following settings:

```
From: /
To: https://themaindomain.com
Type: Permanent # optionally: start with temporary to make sure it works
```

[image]